# Bit manipulation in BigInteger

Tags: java, bit, biginteger

I recently learned a method in BigInteger Java class called

```
BigInteger.testBit(n)
```

Its main function is `(this & (1<<n)) != 0)`, but I do not quite understand the source code

```
return (getInt(n >>> 5) & (1 << (n & 31))) != 0;
```

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with how it's implemented, but judging by that code, I would assume that a BigInteger is implemented by storing it's value in a list of integers, and `getInt(n)` returns the n'th of these, where 0 = least significant.

The first will store the least significant 32 bits, `getInt(1)` will store bits 32-63 etc. By shifting `n` right by 5, you get the index of the integer in the internal list that has the bit you care about, it's the equivalent to n div 32.

With that integer, you then pick out the bit you care about from it with the `(1 << (n & 31))`. n & 31 is the equivalent of n modulo 32, and the `1 <<` is the equivalent of 2^. This gets you a bit mask that selects precisely the bit you care about.

Comment: I'm a little surprised they did `1 << (n & 31)`, since shifts are _automatically_ masked to the low 5 bits.

Comment: That bit's nothing to do with the shift, it's just picking out only the lowest 5 bits with a mask.

Comment: @Flynn1179: that is what Louis says: there is no need to mask out, since shifts values are already masked out to the low 5 bits.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: No, the call to the `getInt` function doesn't shift n by 5 first then pass it in. The value of `n` used by the part of the expression that does `(n & 31)` hasn't been shifted, it's still exactly as passed in to the `testBit` function in the first place.

Comment: @Flynn1179: I know. But in `1 << n`, only the low 5 bits (mask 31 or 0x1F) of n will be used anyway, so `1 << (n & 31)` is equivalent to `1 << n`, because the runtime already masks out the low 5 bits.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was automatically masked. Found info about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19. I can only assume either whoever wrote the code didn't know that either, or just to make it clear what the intent of the code is for anyone maintaining it. Without knowing it's automatically masked, had I just seen (1 << n), I'd have been scratching my head trying to figure out how that could work. The compiler will probably optimize it away, I suspect.